# Seeking spreadsheet template for planning multiple people/city visits

Tags: planning

Are there spreadsheet templates to help plan a several week visit by 6 family units, covering several locations, when not everyone will be in the same place at the same time?  The goal is to see where everyone is at any time, and to see who will be in the same city on any given day.

Comment: Wouldn't a calendar be more useful than a spreadsheet?

Comment: How could a calendar keep track of multiple family units and multiple cities?

Comment: I have seen companies use a matrix to track where people will be on dates extending out into the future.  You could adapt a scheme like that to your purpose without much trouble.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC One colour per family, then add entries like "Smith Family in NYC" and "Jones Family in Paris", then look at the calendar to see where everyone is?

Comment: @Gayot Fow  Can you post an example of such a spreadsheet?

Comment: I added one that has INDICATIVE value only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a itinerary matix...

[image]

It shows three couples on a short trip to Europe.

This example is set for the granularity of one day, but could be increased to morning, afternoon, and evening granularity.

Colour coding is optional.  This example uses orange to indicate international travel.

Greenish colours indicate activities in and around London, and pinkish colours indicate activities in and around Paris.

Using this matrix, it's apparent that 'Fred' wants to stay an extra day in London to see the V&A Museum; 'Mary' wants to see Chantilly while others want to see Chartes. 'Francis', on the other hand, wants to visit her long lost uncle.  'John' and 'Fred' have a special thing for Monet, so they want to visit Giverny.  As shown, everybody is safely home and well rested for the big 4th of July BBQ and fireworks.

You can add notes, annotations, and call-outs to the matrix as needed.